# Case When/ IF Else in Tableau

Tags: if-statement, case, tableau-api, case-when

Can anyone help me to write case when/if else statement.

I created a calculate field Statement. I am not good at writing codes. What I want is:

If I ONLY select status = complete on dashboard, the text on top should only display Case Completed

and

If I select status = pending on dashboard, the text on top should only display Case Closed

and

If I select status = cancel on dashboard, the text on top should only display Case Closed

and if I select multiple then it should only display Case Closed

Currently what's happening if I select multiple it is displaying both text Case Completed and Case Closed.

Here is the link to 
[TWBX FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ULkjPGwBsNkC-dRTdB_xk17epTLAxCkL/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you

Desired Output
[image]

Comment: Can you try rewording your question? Provide a desired result? It's a little unclear what you're looking for with your current question. Also please provide the structure of your data.

Comment: Hello Tim, thanks for replying. I update the question please let me know if it is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost got it. Try this:

```
IF [Status] = "Complete" THEN 'Case Completed'
ELSEIF [Status] = "Pending" OR [Status] = "Cancel" THEN 'Case Closed' 
END
```

Comment: Hello Tm10101, Thanks for replying I update the question to be more clear. Even if I update the code that you provided it is still having the same issue.